# Lower Bound to Measure Entanglement in Mixed States

Tags: entanglement

Given a mixed state with a $n$ qubit density matrix of the following structure:
$$
\rho=\pmatrix{\lambda_1&&&&\nu\\&\lambda_2\\ &&\lambda_{\dots}\\ &&&\lambda_2\\ \nu&&&&\lambda_1},
$$
so a mixture of a GHZ state and a sum of diagonal contributions of the form: $\prod Z_k^{x_k}$, where $x_k$ is the $k$th bit of the binary number $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, which is restricted to contain an even number of $1$s. The latter restriction ensures that the matrix is symmetric w.r.t. the anti-diagonal.

If all $\lambda_k$ are equal, there is a way to measure exponentially small amounts of the GHZ state, as proposed [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12934/5280). It looks to me, that my states don't respect the graph diagonal state requirement given in the comments.

What is the best lower bound for $\nu$, that is efficiently measurable (involving polynomially many measurements)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you impose that $\lambda_x=\lambda_{\bar x}$, your state is of the form that my previous results apply to. This is because you can write
$$
|x\rangle\langle x|+|\bar x\rangle\langle\bar x|=\frac{1}{2}(|x\rangle+|\bar x\rangle)(\langle x|+\langle\bar x|)+\frac{1}{2}(|x\rangle-|\bar x\rangle)(\langle x|-\langle\bar x|),
$$
and so this state is diagonal in the GHZ-state basis. This is easily rotated into the graph state basis of a star graph using Hadamards.

Let $y\in\{0,1\}^n$ be the choice that gives the largest value of $\lambda_y$ ($y\neq 000\ldots 0$ or $111\ldots 1$). Choose $y$ to specify your bipartition of the qubits. This is entangled when $\lambda_y<\nu$.

Comment: thanks. When I apply $H\otimes H$ to $ZZ$, I get $XX$. To be diagonal in the star graph state bases, this should commute with all $K_y$. But for the  latter I get $11,XZ,ZX,YY$. Looks like I got something wrong, right?

Comment: The stabilizers for the GHZ states are $\{Z_iZ_{i+1}\}_{i=1}^{n-1}$ and $X^{\otimes n}$. If you apply Hadamards to all but the first qubit, you get $Z_1X_2$, $\{X_iX_{i+1}\}_{i=2}^{n-1}$ and $X_1Z_2Z_3\ldots Z_n$. These do commute with the stabilizer generators, which are $\{Z_1X_i\}_{i=2}^n$ and $X_1Z_2Z_3\ldots Z_n$

Comment: The way that I see this is that I use the graph state stabilizers to construct the stabilizers that I want. For example, $X_iX_{i+1}$ can be written as $(Z_1X_i)(Z_1X_{i+1})$.